# How did Han Solo's hands get freed on Cloud City (whilst he was in the carbon-freezing chamber)

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back, han-solo

When Hans first enters the carbon-freeze chamber, his hands are tied by the Ugnauts.

[image: Han Entering Carbon Freeze]

However, when he is encased in carbonite, his hands had clearly been freed at some point, and were free at the time of freezing.

[image: Jazz-Hans!]

[Jazz-Hans]

My questions are: (even though i know it's probably yet another Star Wars plot inconsitency, I want to know if there's some kind of canonical answer.)

1. At what point were Han's hands freed
2. How did he do it- if he did it himself
3. If it wasn't him who did it and why (why not just free him)

Yes, I know I'm overthinking it.

But it's time I learned the truth about Han-Houdini.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The film's [junior novel](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1484709144) indicates that the Ugnaught guards removed them:

> Two Ugnaughts approached Han, removed the manacles from his wrists,
> then stepped away from him. Leia watched the lift descend, carrying
> Han down into the central pit. From where Leia stood, only Han’s head
> was visible. His gaze never strayed from her.

Which you can see in this scene just before Han is placed into the carbonite chamber.

[image]

Interestingly, both the script and the official novelisation disagree, stating that he was firmly bound before being placed into the chamber.

---

As to the bindings on his upper arms, those were *already made of carbonite* and hence melted away when Leia unfroze him, according to Steve Sansweet, former Head of Content/Head of Fan Relations for Lucasfilm.

> **Q. When Han Solo is being put into carbon freeze (The Empire Strikes
> Back), his hands are cuffed. When he comes out of the chamber his
> hands are up in the air and spread apart. Also, when he is thawed in
> Jedi, the bindings are gone. How does this happen?**
>
> **A.** *The Ugnaughts remove the bindings on Han's hands before he is lowered
> into the chamber. If you watch carefully you should be able to catch
> it. **The bindings that are on his upper arms are made of carbonite, and
> thus melt away when Leia releases Han from his carbonite coffin.***
>
> <sub><sup>[Ask the Lucasfilm Jedi Council - Starwars.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20030414174910/http://www.starwars.com:80/community/askjc/steve/askjc20001016.html)</sup></sub>

Comment: Well, he's still got those things on his upper arms. So in that sense, he is "firmly bound".

Comment: @JohnSensebe - They don't seem especially robust. Presumably he broke free of them.

Comment: Having just watched the scene where he's freed, carbonite also tucks your shirt in better for you.

Comment: @Mazura It really would be quite useless if it didn't to that as a minimum of courtesy. Least you can expect, really.

Comment: @JohnSensebe - See edit.